# Chart Location in excel vba

Tags: sql, xcode

***how to set chart location i have below code***

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim cht As Object
```

'Your data range for the chart

```
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("C10:Q12")
```

'Create a chart

```
 Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2
```

'Give chart some data

```
 cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng
```

'Determine the chart type

```
cht.Chart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
```

'Change chart's title

```
  cht.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Budget vs Actual (Income)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean, location of chart on the worksheet?

First, you're better off using this to declare`cht`:

```
Dim cht As ChartObject
```

Then to locate `cht`, you can use (for example):

```
cht.Left = 150
cht.Top = 100
```

or tie `cht` to a cell's location:

```
cht.Left = ActiveSheet.Range("D4").Left
cht.Top = ActiveSheet.Range("D4").Top
```